# Renaming OSX .app causes crash

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview, appkit

Trying to find a solution to a user renaming a .app application in the Applications directory. Specifically what's happening is if a user renames the application loading nibs will fail.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {
    NSString* nibName = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if (self) {
        if ([[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName
                                          owner:self
                                topLevelObjects:nil]) {
            [self configureView];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"FAILED TO LOAD THE NIB");
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

The way nibs are being loaded is through the mainBundle but if that name changes in the wild then there is unexpected behavior. I was wondering if there is a solution for how to handle this kind of edge case as I did not find anything in my initial google searching.

Comment: I tried this and can't reproduce the crash.

Comment: You need to go into the products folder in Xcode and rename your .app to something different. Then trigger an action that would require loading a nib programmatically like the code above. It will fail when you do that. I was able to recreate it again in a test project.

Comment: Do you rename the app while it is running?

Comment: Yeah, renaming the applicaiton while it's open will cause the issue. OSX will warn you that you that this action will cause unexpected results. However, it is a possible edge case that I'd like to prevent if at all possible.

Comment: I would show an alert and quit.

Comment: I wouldn't mind doing something like that. The problem is I have many many places where I would have to check for that logic in the case of failed nib loads. While I can go down that route if need be, I would much rather like to see if there is any way to subscribe to or detect that change when it happens in runtime and react accordingly.

Comment: Search SO for `[cocoa] detect rename file`.